# Are there any tweaks for port forwarding a mobile hotspot connection?

Tags: iphone, network, wifi, jailbreak, tethering

I'm currently using an iPhone 6s jailbroken with unc0ver. I also have an unlimited plan from AT&T, if that matters. I'm using tetherme to unlock tethering, and use it to connect to the internet on my Windows 10 machine. Are there any tweaks out there or other third party solutions that I could use to port forward and host servers from my Windows 10 machine connected to my iPhone hotspot? I've searched around a little and most information is old and not pertaining to jailbroken devices. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Most mobile phone networks I've used are NATed which would prevent this from working.

Comment: @Scottmeup I forgot to mention in the OP, but I'm using an unlimited plan from AT&T, not sure if this changes anything or if you know any specifics about that, but just wanted to put that out there

Comment: You should be able to ssh into your iphone and check it's network address. If the IP address attached to the cellular data network is a member of a private network range you are definitely behind a NAT.